# Adding a row and column from a list to a csv in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, matrix

I am new to python and I want to run a pairwise similarity algorithm over a bunch of vectors(vectors.csv). Each vector is a representation of a node. 
I have vectors.csv file that contains:

```
    1,2,3
    4,5,6
    7,8,9
```

and I have a list that has y = [56,76,87] depicting the nodes.

I want to get a .csv file that will contain:

```
    null,56,76,87
    56,1,2,3
    76,4,5,6
    87,7,8,9
```

What is the best way to do this in python3?

The matrix in the csv is a numpy array.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Join the list to the array (concatenate), and then use `savetxt` on the new array.

Comment: You can use `pandas.DataFrame(matrix, index=[56,76,87], columns=[56,76,87])`. In numpy it will be a bit awkward since the `[0, 0]` is missing and I suppose that you don't want to run any computations on the node ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas` may help you.

```
import pandas as pd
y = [56,76,87]
c=pd.read_csv("vector.csv", names=y)
c.index=y
```

this will give you that:

```
    56 76 87
56  1  2  3
76  4  5  6
87  7  8  9
```

and you finally export the newly generated data

```
c.to_csv('new_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Define the array and label list:

```
In [67]: arr = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)
In [68]: y = [56,76,87]
```

join the label list to array:

```
In [69]: arr1 = np.column_stack((y,arr))
```

define a header line:

```
In [70]: header = 'null,' + ','.join([str(i) for i in y])
In [71]: header
Out[71]: 'null,56,76,87'
```

write with `savetxt`.  Note use of header, comments and fmt parameters.  Play with those if needed:

```
In [72]: np.savetxt('test.txt', arr1,header=header, fmt='%d',delimiter=',',comments='')
In [73]: cat test.txt
null,56,76,87
56,1,2,3
76,4,5,6
87,7,8,9
```

`savetxt` writes the header with comment character.  Then it iterates over the rows (1st dim) of the array array.  For each row it does a `fmt%tuple(row)` write, where `fmt` is derived from your parameter.  So at its core it's a standard Python file write of formatted lines.

Answer (score 0):

Let me take a crack at this.

"The matrix in the csv is a numpy array."

Not necessarily.  If you're file is a .csv file, then you can use the csv package and import data like this:

```
import os
import csv

root = r'C:\path\to\my\csv\file'
input_file_name = r'input_data.csv'
output_file_name = r'new_data.csv'

input_path = os.path.join(root, input_file_name)
output_path = os.path.join(root, output_file_name)
```

Import our data:

```
with open(input_path, 'r', newline ='') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    data = [i for i in csv_reader]
f.close()
```

Then you'll have a list of lists (which is like an array, but is a list data type in Python):

```
[[' 1', '2', '3'], [' 4', '5', '6'], [' 7', '8', '9']]
```

Here's our y values, which I assumed were integers:

```
y = [56,76,87]
```

I borrowed a useful function from here:
[Converting elements of list of nested lists from string to integer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46548902/converting-elements-of-list-of-nested-lists-from-string-to-integer-in-python)

```
def int_conversion(my_list):
    return [int(x) if not isinstance(x, list) else int_conversion(x) for x in my_list]
```

Our function does some data type conversion, but outputs integer values:

```
def process_data(my_data=data):
    # copy the raw data list
    new_data = my_data

    # Convert our y values to stings for processing
    y_1 = [str(i) for i in y]

    # Insert each value of our y list at the first spot in each sublist
    for i in range(len(my_data)):
        new_data[i].insert(0, y_1[i])

    # Insert a '0' placeholder at the start of our y list
    y_1.insert(0, '0')

    # Insert the y list as a sublist in our main data list
    new_data.insert(0, y_1)

    # Convert the list values to integers
    new_data = int_conversion(new_data)

    # Replace the first value in the first sublist with a null (None) value
    new_data[0][0] = None

    # Return the results
    return new_data
```

Process and then write the output:

```
data = process_data()

with open(output_path, mode='w', newline='') as xyz:
    writer = csv.writer(xyz)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Then your file should look something like this:

```
,56,76,87
56,1,2,3
76,4,5,6
87,7,8,9
```

Answer (score -1):

Since conceptually your first row and first column represent *labels*, you may wish to consider Pandas, which builds on NumPy array objects:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

x = """1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9"""

# read data; replace StringIO(x) with 'file.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x), header=None)

# define column and index properties
idx = [56,76,87]
df.columns = idx
df.index = idx

# export to csv
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```